# Jquery Ajax Data Key Name defining with a Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am defining a key for 'id', instead of the variable 'action_upd's value(which is "action"), my php reads literally 'action_upd' and not the value

If I do in my php:

```
if($_POST['action_upd']){ echo "Action"}
```

my $.ajax will do --> alert "Action"

```
action_upd = "'" + action_upd + "'";  <-- same result
```

.

```
action_upd = "action";//used to be 'cow' if you check some comments
id = "1234";//just an id of an item    

$.ajax({            
    type: 'POST',
    url: './DB/DB.php',
    data: { action_upd:id,'val': val},
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error : function(result){
        alert(result + "error");
    }
});
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: I can't even figure out why you do `action_upd = "cow";` before the .ajax. I mean, where does `id` even come from? Or `val` for that matter.

Comment: you can use a variable as property-key if you wrap it in square brackets like this `data: {[action_upd]:id,'val': val}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seperated 'action_upd' and 'id', my idea was the key would change dependent of an option i choosed and would have the id

//original

data: { action_upd:id ,'val': val},

if 'action_upd' was (for example) 'update_item', if(isset($_POST['update_item'])){ update();}

//end result

data: { 'action_upd':action_upd,'id':id,'val': val},
need an extra if to check action_upd was iniciated then check the action

Answer (score 0):

Put action_upd in quotes if you want it to be a string and not a variable. Otherwise your code will do `cow:id` instead of `action_upd:id` when executed

```
$.ajax({            
    type: 'POST',
    url: './DB/DB.php',
    data: { 'action_upd':id,'val': val},
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error : function(result){
        alert(result + "error");
    }
});
```

Comment: No, your answer is wrong about keynames and how jquery uses the object. It does not replace `action_upd` with `cow`, because it will not interpret that as a variable for replacement. This is why you see tons of people doing like: `data: { data: data, status: status }` when passing to ajax. Which is valid (although unreadable).